# How to get IndexPath of specify row in Tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I got a tableView with 10 rows. Because of I want to get the third cell of my TableView. So I have to get the indexPath of row number 3. How can I do that?
I tried:

```
            var sections = self.diceFaceTable.numberOfSections()
            var indexPathOfLastSelectedRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: sections)

            var lastSelectedCell = self.diceFaceTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathOfLastSelectedRow) as! TableViewCell
```

But I got an error. How can I got that?

Edit:

[image]

I got a table with some check mark image. I want to uncheck the last row before check the selected row with my code:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cell = self.diceFaceTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DiceFaceTableViewCell
    if selectedDiceFace != indexPath.row {

        var indexPathOfLastSelectedRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedDiceFace, inSection: 0)
        println("indextPath: \(indexPath)")
        println("indextPathOfLastSelectedRow: \(indexPathOfLastSelectedRow)")
        println("selectedDiceFace: \(selectedDiceFace)")
        println("selectedRow: \(indexPath.row)")
        var lastSelectedCell = self.diceFaceTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathOfLastSelectedRow) as! DiceFaceTableViewCell
        lastSelectedCell.selectedImg.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck")

        selectedDiceFace = indexPath.row
        cell.selectedImg.image = UIImage(named: "check")


    }

    cell.setSelected(false, animated: true)

}
```

I can got the last selected cell and uncheck that and check the select row. everything working fine except if I scrolling the table and after that if I check the new row. I will got the crash with error about to "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" at line:

```
var lastSelectedCell = self.diceFaceTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathOfLastSelectedRow) as! DiceFaceTableViewCell
```

I don't know what's problem in my code that can lead me to that problem with I scroll the table and after that select the row.

Answer (score 2):

Sections are also numbered from 0, so you need to specify `inSection` as 0:

```
var indexPathOfLastSelectedRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)
```

This is of course if you have only one section.

Comment: pretty useless answer if only valid in a trivial case: 'This is of course if you have only one section.'